# No warning: [-Wdangling-gsl] for auto variable

Tags: c++

In this code:

```
std::wstring g_tmp = L"123";
std::wstring_view foo1() {
    return g_tmp;
}

std::wstring foo() {
    std::wstring tmp = L"err";
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    auto v = foo1();
    if (v.empty()) {
        v = foo(); // (1) no warning here
    }
    
    std::wstring_view v2 = foo(); // (2) only here
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qbfTf4s9M

I have warning:

```
<source>:23:28: warning: object backing the pointer will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression [-Wdangling-gsl]
    std::wstring_view v2 = foo();
```

Is it a limitation / error in compiler (clang 16) that in (1) there is no warning, only in (2)?

This problem in (1) was discovered using clang sanitizater, but I would like to see it earlier during compilation.

Comment: Undefined behavior is not required to be diagnosable in general. Any warning you get is a best effort on the compilers part, no more (and therefore isn't something to be expected). This is why one should run additional checks, sanitizers, and tests to rule out as many bugs as possible.

Comment: I believe this warning is only triggered during initialization.  You can tell by changing your last like to `std::wstring_view v2 = foo1(); v2 = foo();`

Comment: Probably a compiler limitation. Whoever programmed this warning didn't program it for operator=. They should do that, and you could file a bug report.

Comment: Out of curiosity, for `-Wdangling-gsl` ... what does the "gsl" part of that mean?  Is that for "Guidelines Support Library"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a limitation of the compiler.

For comparison, I tested the same code in Visual Studio 2022, using MSVC 14.35 and C++ compiler version 19.35, and I got warnings [C26815](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26815?view=msvc-170) and [C26449](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26449?view=msvc-170) referring to your line (1): `v = foo();`.

So yes, ideally the compiler should be giving warnings on your line (1). You can report this as a GitHub issue on the [LLVM GitHub page](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues), and hope that they add support for giving warnings on lines of code such as this.